# ApexCharts high performance scatter chart

Tags: performance, scatter, apexcharts

I've created a mixed chart (line/column/scatter) that receives around +5000 data points. The performance drops when implementing it with the scatter charts because of the set marker sizes.

I've followed the performance guide mentioned in https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/214 that recommends disabling animations, markers and data labels. The chart performed well but by adding scatter points where you've to set the marker size the performance dropped.

Is there a way to make a high performance Scatter chart with +5000 data points (main goal is to combine lines and dots for data visualization) ?